# Finding duplicate value in Oracle Sql

Tags: sql

I have a table like below.

```
Id      amount
--------------
10.     12345
10.     12345
12.     34567 
13.     34567
```

As per my business requirement same id with same amount is not duplicate record. different Ids  wtih same amount is duplicate record. hope you understood the requirement.

In the above sample record I have to get the duplicate amount values and its count and at the same time Id should be different.

The expected query result is 34567 and count as 2.

Answer (score 2):

IF you need to display id as well,

```
SELECT a.*
FROM 
(
  SELECT id, amount, count(1) OVER (PARTITION BY amount) num_dup
  FROM table1
)a
WHERE a.num_dup >1
```

**Update**. If you care only about distinct id , use `COUNT(DISTINCT id)` instead of `COUNT(1)`

**More examples**.
With joining another table

```
SELECT a.*
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT a.id, a.amount, 
        count(distinct a.id) OVER (PARTITION BY a.amount) num_dup
      FROM table1 a
      INNER JOIN table2 b ON (b.id = a.id)    
    )a
    WHERE a.num_dup >1
```

Without window function and without table1.id :

```
SELECT a.amount, count(distinct a.id)
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b ON (b.id = a.id)
GROUP BY a.amount
HAVING count(distinct a.id) >1 ;
```

Without window function and with table1.id :

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM 
(
SELECT a.amount, count(distinct a.id)
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b ON (b.id = a.id)
GROUP BY a.amount
HAVING count(distinct a.id) >1 
)a
INNER JOIN table1 b ON (b.amount = a.amount)
```

Comment: Thanj you for ur response. could you please tell me what is the use of Over partition by function

Comment: It's quite large topic for SO. Check "Analytic functions" in Oracle documentation (for instance here - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174)

Comment: The query given by you works perfectly . but when I go for join it is not working. I have to match that Id with some other table say table 2.

Comment: SELECT a.*
FROM 
(
  SELECT id, amount, count(1) OVER (PARTITION BY amount) num_dup
  FROM table1,table 2 where table1.id=table2.id
)a
WHERE a.num_dup >1.

Comment: Syntax seems ok to me; what exactly is not working ? too many results ?

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. Actually i am getting the results with same ID and VALUE instead of DISTINCT ID AND SAME VALUE. FYI Table 2 WON'T have duplicate/same IDs many times.
Table1: (i have given earlier)

Id      amount
--------------
10.     12345
10.     12345
12.     34567 
13.     34567
Table 2:
Id   coulmn X Coulmn Y
10            
12         
13    
You can see that table2 has distinct IDs. Please guide me to achieve the result.
NOTE: Is there any other way to achieve the desired result other than using OVR PARTITION BY. Thanks again for your help on this

Comment: Check updated answer. I'm not 100% sure I got what you want, so I posted couple different versions .

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think there was a communication gap. What result i am looking for is "I have to pull out Same amount with distinct Ids". Answer should be like (based on the details given in the table1 and 2 earlier) Id 12 13 Amount 34567 34567. Also i should get the count of same amount value. Hope this makes sense. I havent tested the query till now. I will check and lt you know the status. Thank you.